# In Boomi Can we import cross reference table in Java script?

Tags: boomi

Is there any chance to import Cross Reference  table to java script in Boomi process?

How to import (Cross Reference  table)CRT to java script. I am trying to import CRT(Cross Reference  table) table to java script in boomi interface

Is there any possibility. Please help me to find it?

Answer (score 0):

That is not currently a possibility as mentioned in the link [here](https://community.boomi.com/s/question/0D51W00006ArzvZSAR/can-you-access-crossreference-tables-in-either-groovy-or-javascript).

But if you would like to work with data that is currently stored in a CRT using JavaScript or Groovy, you should ideally use a map shape and then create a new map function. In this map function, add the CRT you want to work with, and then add a scripting function as the next step to access the needed value. Do let me know if this approach doesn't work with your case for some reason, I would love to help to find any alternate approaches to achieve it.

You can find another solution to a similar requirement [here](https://community.boomi.com/s/question/0D56S0000BPHBWmSQP/can-we-use-cross-reference-table-inside-the-custom-scripting).